# Исчезает слайдер при создании статической страницы

Tags: nuxt.js

Проект на Nuxt.js
При создании статической страницы и загрузке на домен исчезает слайдер, как решить проблему? Слайдер прописан в компонентах и добавлен на главную через импорт компонента, точно также как и все остальные компоненты. Код слайдера vue-bootstrap

```html
<template>
     <div class="slider-home">
         <b-row>
             <b-col xl="8" lg="12">
                    <b-carousel
    id="slider-home"
    style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000"
    fade
    indicators
    img-width="1024"
    img-height="480"
  >
    <b-carousel-slide
      caption=""
      img-src="../assets/img/slider-home/2.jpg"
    >
        <div class="slider-home-slide-1">
                  <a href="#!"><h5 class="white-text">Сыворотка молодости</h5><p class="white-text">Новая формула, Результаты видны уже через час</p><div class="text-right"><b-button size="sm"  class="black-text" >Подробнее</b-button></div> </a>
                </div>
    </b-carousel-slide>
    <b-carousel-slide
      caption=""
      img-src="../assets/img/slider-home/_2.jpg"
    ><div class="slider-home-slide-1">
                  <a href="#!"><h5 class="white-text">Сыворотка молодости</h5><p class="white-text">Новая формула, Результаты видны уже через час</p><div class="text-right"><b-button size="sm"  class="black-text" >Подробнее</b-button></div></a>
                </div></b-carousel-slide>
    <b-carousel-slide
      caption=""
      img-src="../assets/img/slider-home/2.jpg"
      
    ><div class="slider-home-slide-1">
                  <a href="#!"><h5 class="white-text">Сыворотка молодости</h5><p class="white-text">Новая формула, Результаты видны уже через час</p><div class="text-right"><b-button size="sm"  class="black-text" >Подробнее</b-button></div></a>
                </div></b-carousel-slide>
    <b-carousel-slide
      caption=""
      img-src="../assets/img/slider-home/_2.jpg"
    ><div class="slider-home-slide-1">
                  <a href="#!"><h5 class="white-text">Сыворотка молодости</h5><p class="white-text">Новая формула, Результаты видны уже через час</p><div class="text-right"><b-button size="sm"  class="black-text" >Подробнее</b-button></div></a>
                </div></b-carousel-slide>
  </b-carousel>
             </b-col>
             <b-col class="slider-home-row-right">
             <b-row>
                <b-col>
                <div class="slider-home-right-top">
                  <a href="#!"><h5 class="white-text">Здоровые волосы-это просто!</h5><div class="text-right"><b-button size="sm"  class="black-text" >Подробнее</b-button></div></a>
                </div>
                </b-col>
                
                <b-col>
                <div class="slider-home-right-bottom">
                  <a href="#!"><h5 class="black-text">Как подобрать импланты</h5><div class="text-right"><b-button size="sm"  class="black-text" >Подробнее</b-button></div></a>
                </div>
                 </b-col>
                 
             </b-row>
             </b-col>
             
         </b-row>
     </div>
   
</template>
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу проблемный участок кода, без него мы не можем помочь.
Какой слайдер, как он вызывался и прочее.

Comment: а он при generate в разметке хоть появляется ?

Comment: https://beautystars.life/

Comment: да появляется, только не отображается

Comment: попробуйте [vue-awesome-swiper](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper), с ним проблем не должно быть

Comment: все работает, просто проект нормально не сбилдился, еще раз сделала и все заработало. Всем спасибо!